# Two computers clean installing latest version of Ubuntu 20.10 not working

Tags: boot, system-installation, 20.10, cursor

Today, the computer my company got me arrived and I had to install Ubuntu on it.

After attempting several times to install Ubuntu 20.10 (and also 20.04), the only result I got was the blinking underscore cursor. Then I though "an older version might be more stable", so I tried to install 18.04, which bricked the computer (installation froze, and button shutdown did the trick).

Being this the second computer that I get from my company, they asked me to work with my personal computer until we figure what computer to actually buy (small company, no IT department ;) ). So I set out to clean install my personal computer, which was already running 20.10 Groovy. "I'm reinstalling the same OS it's already running. What could go wrong?" I thought.

Well, now I also have the blinking cursor problem on my personal laptop and zero idea of what to do or how to debug. I don't even know what kind of bug to report.

I remember having to search the internet for some specific driver for the network card (turns out it's a little special) but I don't recall all this fuss or having to manually launch `startx` from tty2, with the "There's been an error" window opening every two minutes.

It really staggered me that seconds ago I was running this exact version of the OS

Can I ask for some guidance? Thanks in advance! :D

PS: Already installed vendor nvidia drivers, didn't solve anything.

#### EDIT

The make of the computer is Xiaomi Mi Air 13 and the output of `lshw -c video` is:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:137 memory:b2000000-b2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP108M [GeForce MX150]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:138 memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
```

Comment: Hi!  It will help if you present a little information about your system (make and model at the least) and perhaps include some of the text accompanying "There's been an error".  Additionally the output of the command `sudo lshw -c video` may be of some help.

Comment: The first is a dell inspiron 7400. It is bricked, so I can't get any more information from the laptop. The second one, my PC is a Xiaomi Mi Air 13 and the output of `sudo lshw -c video` ...

EDIT I-ll add it to the question because it does not fit a comment :)

Comment: Have you tried using `nomodeset` in the linux command line at boot time?

Comment: Dell indicates that [unpluggin the AC line, removing the battery and pressing power](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000130881/dell-pc-does-not-turn-on-or-boot-into-windows) may help you restart the 7400

Comment: and please run the command `lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'` to show which video card you are using.  I'm going to type a longer comment, about a very similar problem that my computer is back in the shop for.

Comment: My own primary computer (I'm using the one I meant to drop off at the thrift store) has dual NVidia and Intel GPUs.  When I run in hybrid mode, or try to boot in NVidia only mode, I must press ctrl+alt+f2 and then ctrl+alt+f1 to get the graphical interface up.  I could also get the graphics running with sudo systemctl start gdm3, or startx.  My computer is currently at the mfgr's shop, trying to have this diagnosed, as extensive communications and reinstalls of Ubuntu repeat this problem, when the kernel is updated.  They apparently think that it is an obscure, relatively rare hardware issue.

Comment: Basically, I'm saying check your nvidia driver and put the system into integrated graphics mode, reboot and see if that makes things a little better.